# Логин, пароль и регистрация

Tags: html, css, javascript

Возможно ли реализовать регистрацию пользователя на JS? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверку введенных данных - можно. Регистрацию с занесением в БД - нет, для этого нужно хотя бы php.
И надо помнить, что проверка данных пишется только для удобства пользователя, так как пользователь может отключить JS. Поэтому полагаться только на нее нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Все можно :)
Штука называется серверный javascript. Займусь им как-нибудь, но пока мне в работе нужен js/css/html/php/mysql/oracle/postgresql и не более :)

http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/27915/